# What the heck is this, when my cursor is on that, it disappears?

Tags: windows-10, virus, virus-removal

[image]

do not know  how it is uploaded or is it a program of ASUS, but it appears everytime until my mouse on it and it disappears, can not figure out what is this?

Comment: it's a built-in windows feature (since at least windows 7), it's called notification area, and moving your mouse there shows you all the hidden icons. Google for "windows 10 notification area"

Comment: It’s a tray icon that wasn’t properly cleaned up by the program that created it. When, exactly, is “everytime”? Every time you turn on your PC?

Comment: Its not a virus.  In order to identify what program it goes to, you will have to use Autoruns, and not load all your programs and one by one identify which programs add which icons.

Comment: @DanielB it stays on always, it just disappears for a minute when the cursor of the mouse is on the icon, then it appears back.

Comment: @MátéJuhász what a funny explanation, a kid knows what it is the notification area. it is maybe my mistake did not highlight the icon which gives me problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I captured an image of the icon in question, ran it through [Google's reverse image search with the key words "Asus icon"](https://www.google.ca/search?hl=en-CA&q=asus%20icon&tbm=isch&imgil=xxmVSAF2nozMqM%253A%253BLCs53P6aNh7ccM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.asus.com%25252Fus%25252Fsupport%25252FFAQ%25252F1018727%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&tbs=simg:CAESkAEJh7Fs9sICYyAahAELEKjU2AQaAggEDAsQsIynCBpdClsIAxIj2AE5K0bxFkCYFwGMC_1EL_1TOgN-Io3Sj7M_18z_1DO3N_1kz4CgaMP38R4LzwJHYQIAFGu0VzSKPjIloVlEEFMozUVviQMWjHOAKpFWa0NM20_1m3XTxEESAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIES_1THeww&fir=xxmVSAF2nozMqM%253A%252CLCs53P6aNh7ccM%252C_&usg=___0CSczx40eYg5WaaA7yfneWOL-M%3D&biw=1345&bih=953&ved=0ahUKEwivgYrviPTQAhVH6oMKHaYYBw4QyjcIRQ&ei=mW5RWO_QMcfUjwSmsZxw#imgrc=xxmVSAF2nozMqM%3A) and it returned similar images that helped me identify it as Asus's LiveUpdate:

[image: Asus LiveUpdate]

It's probably vanishing because it's not closing cleanly (for whatever reason) and as such the visual caching for its entry in the notification area isn't being updated until you mouse-over it, at which point the program is found to be not running and the icon gets removed from view.

Comment: Cool. Tried that earlier, but it didn't work for me.  Maybe I cropped it wrong.

Comment: @chatay Along with "many many thanks" you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).